# Batching writes to the DB in JSF session scope & writing at the end of user session. Is this approach correct?

Tags: java, jsf

In my application, whenever a user performs any activity I need to send an update to his followers. This requires retrieving the followers list, at first, from the DB.
So for each update operation I need to retrieve the list & then write to those from list of followers.

Since there may be multiple times that the app may need to write an update for a user's followers while user in session, thus I'm wandering what if I can batch those write operations. So,

**Should database write operations be batched by first storing the user's activity data in JSF session map?** and **then performing batch write operations at the end of session (or after certain timed interval or some threshold no. of updates) !?**

Perhaps a way to implement this could be, using the `@PreDestroy` method of a `@SessionScoped` bean !? Before destroying I would ask to play all the write operations, that are in stock, to the DB. This way I could save lot of reads and batch multiple writes related to same tables.

*(User Experience wise, there is no issue if they get the update this much late.)*